# Spring: DTO and service layer

Tags: spring, service, dao, layer, dto

I'm using the current layer topology:

1) dao
2) service
3) controllers(presentation)

In one of my controllers I'm receiving the following call (from clients):

```
public PlayerStatisticsDTO getPlayerStatistics(int playerId);
```

The controller should now delegate the call to the service layer.

Problem is, if i create a method like:

```
public PlayerStatisticsDTO getPlayerStatistics(int playerId);
```

in my Service I'm actually making my service layer aware of the DTO object!

I believe this is a bad practice (or not?)

So my other alternative that i came up with is creating a new class:

```
public class PlayerStatistics {...}
```

and then calling in my controller:

```
 PlayerStatistics stats = this.service.getPlayerStatistics(playerID);
 return toDTO(stats);
```

The problem with this solution is that i dont have any use for this class at all in my project so it seems like an unnecessary duplicated code

Comment: what is your problem i did not understand?

Comment: I dont want to make my service layer familiar with my DTO classes

Comment: you want direct access of dto to your controller is't it? what way you want moduralize?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a one on one mapping between the data requested and being presented, using the DTO object in the presentation layer is not a bad practice.
If you would change your presentation layer at a later stage, then you can create a new POJO containing the presentation attribute and map them in the service layer.